Which component within a CPU incurs the most power consumption?
I am studying the situation where power consumption causes CPU frequency reduction. I want to construct a workload that can generate the highest possible power consumption and trigger the frequency reduction. Considering that a CPU micro-architecture consists of multiple components, including instruction fetch, decoding, issue, execution, branch prediction, among others, as well as cache, memory controller, MMU, TLB, etc.
Generally speaking, which components have the largest power consumption during operation? How should I code specifically to target these components?

Usual advice I’ve heard is to run Prime95 in stress test mode. Certainly seems to make my machine work quite hard! Details here: https://www.mersenne.org/download/#stresstest

@nneonneo - Prime95 keeps the SIMD FMA units active every clock cycle.  Those units have the most transistors that switch every cycle when active, which is why they're the highest power.  Plus it does significant SIMD loads, getting that part of the CPU working, too.

@nneonneo Last weekend, I tried Prime95, which is indeed a great stress testing tool. I ran it using ./mprime -m and the default options, which caused my CPU frequency to drop below the base frequency (possibly due to AVX512 instructions). However, I noticed that the load generated by Prime95 over the past 48 hours was not very stable, but showed clear stages. The stages are as follows: every 12 hours, the retired_sse_avx_flops indicator will fluctuate high to low (high is 15 GFLOPs/s, low is 5 GFLOPs/s); memory bandwidth will show the opposite fluctuation in the same cycle.

When retired_sse_avx_flops hits the low point (at this time, memory bandwidth utilization hits the peak), the CPU load is still at 100%, but the frequency goes up to the turbo frequency. Why does Prime95 have such different stages? Which stage is the real stress test? How can I differentiate between them?

Is it because I used the blend mode?

Try the torture test. Depending on your settings, you may have inadvertently set it to actually find primes - which would involve several different stages of computations with different workloads.
